# Grunt plugin process

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-plugins

I'm new on Grunt, and recently I've create a task-runner in order to control my deployments. After, I published my `Gruntfile.js` to npm (because I intent to share with other developments same experience) but it does work properly when calling `grunt` statement.

Could someone explain me where should I start ? I read Grunt documentation, but plugins part is not well explained.

BR
Arthur Silva

Comment: How is that you published your `Gruntfile.js` to `npm`? What you want to achieve? What you grunt task does?

Comment: I've published through `npm publish`. The expectation is to create one central `Gruntfile.js` containing tasks needed for a internal build process (lint, watch, concat, min, and so on). The idea to have it published on `npm` is that developer may pull it into their projects, being a task runner universal inside of company landscape.

Comment: Did you take a look at the `npm publish` docs? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish

Comment: the problem is not related to publish to npm, but in reuse Gruntfile in other projects

Comment: Did you include in your project (and publication) the `package.json`?